# Unable to add data to Firebase in Android (Rules set to true)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase.

I am trying to add a Title and some Text to my Firebase Database. I've set the Rules for write and read to true.
**Edit:**
Copy pasted this exact same code to another Android Studio project and set up a new Firebase project and ran this **exact same code on my phone.** It added data to the Firebase database.
I don't know if I should be happy or sad it did.

This is the class from which data is to be sent:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    EditText titleText;
    EditText postText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("");
        titleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_title);
        postText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_text);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("PostsText");

        Button postButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);

        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(titleText!=null && postText!=null ) {
                    TextPost textPost = new TextPost(titleText.getText().toString(),postText.getText().toString());
                    mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(textPost).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this,"Yes!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this,"No!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    titleText.setText("");
                    postText.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this,"Post uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this,"Empty fields!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the TextPost class whose object I am pushing into the Firebase Database:

```
public class TextPost {
    String title;
    String text;

    public TextPost() {
    }

    public TextPost(String title, String text) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

When I run the CreateActivity and press "Post", the toast pops up saying "Post uploaded", but my Firebase Database in the console still reads "null".
**Also, a toast saying "Yes!" or "No!" does NOT pop up!**

**I have also added the google-services.json file to my app folder.**

Here's my logs after opening the CreateActivity, typing in the Title and Text and clicking on Post:

```
06-27 00:45:09.323 24528-24528/com.android.example.prototype I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=12 eventTime = 648344822 downTime = 648344822 title= com.android.example.prototype/com.android.example.prototype.CreateActivity
06-27 00:45:10.850 24528-24553/com.android.example.prototype W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
06-27 00:45:12.737 24528-24528/com.android.example.prototype I/ViewRootImpl: finishMotionEvent: handled = true stage=10: View Post IME stage,inputElapseTime=13 eventTime = 648348239 downTime = 648348239 title= com.android.example.prototype/com.android.example.prototype.CreateActivity
```

Can someone please help me figure this one out?
Let me know if you need any more info.

My build.gradle dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.daprlabs.aaron:swipedeck:2.0.6'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

[This is my debug screen after getting a Database reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAXVF.jpg)

The debugger skips the addOnCompleteListener method completely and goes directly to setting the titleText and postText to blank.
Any ideas what I should try digging into further or any particular variables that I should look into?

Comment: I highly recommend using `Log` statements or a debugger to figure out code flow. Toasts are notoriously easy to miss. Aside from that: are you sure the device has an internet connection when you run the app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I do have an internet connection while posting.
I'll try using the debugger. I've spent almost two hours trying to figure out what's wrong with this now.

Comment: Well when i am stuck somewhere like you are i start placing Log.i statements almost everywhere in my code to see my code flow. I generally find my mistake. And pls it is a far better method to use Log for testing flow and not a toast.

Comment: I added an image after debugging and changed my Toasts to Logs. The database is getting the correct reference url, however, it isn't writing. Can you recommend any variables I should check or any other idea I can try?

Comment: Check your logcat output for warning messages indicating Google Play services is out of date or missing.

Comment: @BobSnyder I have added this to my app build.gradle -->  
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
Does this indicate that I have used google play services? The logcat isn't giving any warnings about Google Play services.

Comment: No, the plugin is not related to my question.  Most (maybe all) Firebase APIs require the device to have a compatible version of Google Play services installed.  If you aren't seeing any warnings, you're okay.  You can confirm by going to _Settings > Application Manager_ and finding Google Play services. To be certain you have a network connection, consider [adding a connection listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: I copy pasted the CreateActivity class, TextPost class and the associated layout file to another Android Studio project and ran the code. It added data to my new Firebase Database! Do you think the problem is with some other classes/files?

Comment: I suspect the issue is because of authentication (I've enabled sign-in method) for the app. I'll try to modify my code to support that and set my .read and .write to authenticate instead of "true". I'll let you guys know if it works. Thanks for the help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my laptop, tried writing to the Firebase database. It worked. 
No idea how.

Thanks for the help!